Update method parameter during the run
I am wondering if there is a way in JAVA to recall and update argument of the method during the run. My problem is as below
class A
String a = "string that changes in time"; // it gets text from web element

String b = "string to compare";

B.conditionalWait(a.eqals(b));

class B

conditionalWait(boolean condition){
 int numTries = 3;
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 while (numTries-- != 0){
  if(condition) {
   break;
  } else {
     action.pause(5000);
     driver.navigate().refresh();
  }
 }
}


Does JAVA allows in any way to pull the new value of the string, that will changes after refresh of the page?
I do not event know if it is possible to implement it in this way as I want to

Java passes method arguments as values and you therefore cannot change the value that was passed at method call time from outside the method.
What you can do: you can pass a different value. Instead of passing in the evaluated condition you could pass in a java.util.function.BooleanSupplier (or a java.util.function.Predicate, the difference being that the test method of the latter takes an argument):
class B

conditionalWait(BooleanSupplier condition) {
  int numTries = 3;
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  while (numTries-- != 0) {
    if (condition.getAsBoolean()) {
      break;
    } else {
      action.pause(5000);
      driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
  }
}

class A
BooleanSupplier condition = () -> {
    String a = "string that changes in time"; // it gets text from web element
    String b = "string to compare";
    return b.equals(a);
};

B.conditionalWait(condition);


